# Android resource linking failed Android studio 3.3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, drawable, xml-drawable

I am getting this error

> "Android resource linking failed
>   C:\Users\xervice111\AndroidStudioProjects\ud843-QuakeReport-starting-point\app\src\main\res\layout\list_item.xml:10:
>   error: resource drawable/magnitude_circle (aka
>   com.example.android.quake
>
> report:drawable/magnitude_circle) not found. error: failed linking
>   file resources."

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKjzc.png)After I added a drawable resource file named "magnitudeCircle.xml". I have done things like clean project, rebuild project, Invalidate and restart etc but the error is still there ...

[This is my magnitubeCircle.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB300.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Background circle for the magnitude value -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/magnitude1" />
    <size
        android:width="36dp"
        android:height="36dp" />
    <corners android:radius="18dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: you write the line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` twice, remove one of them.

Comment: Remove line <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> from your xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> , should be written only once

Comment: check out this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61156480/12283105

Comment: in my case it was typo in xml's app namespace's instruction  `app:****="just_a_typo"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Background circle for the magnitude value -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/magnitude1" />
    <size
        android:width="36dp"
        android:height="36dp" />
    <corners android:radius="18dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Remove one line from your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

There are two import line in your xml.

Answer (score 0):

This error belongs to this line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

because we can not use this tag twice in a single file<[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47473122/7319704)>.

So, remove this line and try this below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Background circle for the magnitude value -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="@color/magnitude1" />
<size
    android:width="36dp"
    android:height="36dp" />
<corners android:radius="18dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your "list_item.xml" file.
Error is at 10th line of list_item.xml file.
builder cannot find "drawable/magnitude_circle" item from your project. So,

1) If you didn't add "magnitude_circle" file in your drawable resource file yet than first add that file into drawable and then try to build project.

2) If you already have that file in drawable then replace `drawable/magnitude_circle` into `@drawable/magnitude_circle`

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

If not work, creat new folder 'drawable-v28(your version)' and then copy the xml file from 'drawable' to it.  Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's because wrong drawable xml

error drawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">\
```

when i change to:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

it fix